# My first coding - Error - A document must be saved with an extension (and without spaces or accents in the name) before being used by a command

Tags: command-line

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{My Equation}
\author{First Last}
\date{July 21, 2020}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{equation}
    K = P_{predicted} H^{T} \Big( H P_{predicted} H^{T}+R\Big) ^{-1}
    \label{eqn:KalmanUpdate}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Amos and welcome to TeX.SE! Your example compiles perfectly, but your title indicates, that you have troubles with your workflow. Can you maybe describe a bit, what OS you are using, what steps you performed to try to compile the document, which editor you are using, etc.? Also can you make a short recognizable title and move all relevant information to your question, please?

Comment: I use Windows 8.1 64-bit. I use Texmaker 5.0.4. I click the run button to quick build and got that error!
Sorry in future I would come up with precise title.